# How can I configure the antdesign input validation icons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I currently need to change the validation icons, and I can't find any options for that.
Using the default form of antd in react, I have the property 'hasFeedback', for example:

```
 <Form.Item hasFeedback>
              {getFieldDecorator('cnpj', {
                initialValue: verifyInitialValue('cnpj'),
                rules: [
                  { required: true, message: message.REQUIRED },
                  { validator: validatorCNPJ }
                ],
                normalize: value => transformCNPJ(value)
              })(<Input placeholder='CNPJ' />)}
```

so I have the default input validation antd icons, I would like to customize these icons, for example

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/9595529/70814675-b7971880-1daa-11ea-8e6e-289b8533f790.PNG

to make it possible
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/9595529/70814716-d39aba00-1daa-11ea-8705-8dd796b4c53c.PNG

Answer (score 3):

I think the last simple way that you can do until, is just use css

```
.ant-form-item-has-success .anticon-check-circle svg {
  display: none;
}

.ant-form-item-has-success .anticon-check-circle::before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff
    url("https://d1nhio0ox7pgb.cloudfront.net/_img/g_collection_png/standard/256x256/check.png") 
    center / 14px 14px no-repeat;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}
```

I created example here
https://codesandbox.io/s/customized-validation-ant-design-demo-0ziqi?file=/index.css

[image custom antd validation icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHclG.png)

Answer (score 0):

So lucky I have just fixed customized icons in antd for menu item, My English is poor and I will do my best to explain the process.

1: log in https://www.iconfont.cn/ fo create your project.
2: search and named your customized icons with  "icon-" prefix, like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyxco.png)
3. use icons in defaultSetting.js, import your icon project *.js

```
  iconfontUrl: '//at.alicdn.com/t/font_1562537_g9xxixlql5t.js',
```

4. last you can use your customized icon with name defined in icon project.

Comment: I was able to understand your solution, but I could not understand how it would be configured. Could you give an example of how you did your project through [Codepen](https://codepen.io/) or another platform, please

Answer (score -1):

you can use suffix property as props in input like:

<Input suffix={(use icons here or can use string 'hello world')}/>

its work fine

Comment: This does not answer OPs question